# Close excel application using Powershell

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am initiating a macro in a workbook from powershell (to automate a process). The below in powershell opens the excel workbook and runs the macro without visualizing the process.

The issue is even though I do not see the macro running, the new instance of excel generated from the macro is still open.

```
# start Excel
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application

#open file
$FilePath = 'C:\file\Book1.xlsm'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)


#access the Application object and run a macro
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("macro")


#close excel
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Start-Sleep 1
'Excel processes: {0}' -f @(Get-Process excel -ea 0).Count
Remove-Variable $excel

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

The excel file still comes up as a process in task manager and is taking up memory space.

How do I have powershell completely close the instance of the excel application that opens through the macro?

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably call book.close / app.quit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using **Quit** method before you release COM object, like this:

```
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
Remove-Variable excel
```

Comment: Great this works, however the macro powershell commands to run from Book1 opens a second workbook that defaults to "Book2". The issue I still have is when I run the script Book2 prompts the user to save the workbook before continuing. How do I close the second workbook as well (so the new active workbook)?

Comment: I resolved by closing the second workbook within the macro, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You could add this to your PS code:

```
kill -processname excel
```

*This will close all open instances of Excel*

Comment: When I do this, and restart Excel with the workbook that was loaded when I killed the process, Excel displays a Document Recovery window.  I'm looking for a more graceful way to shut down Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Creating the Excel file:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
...
```

Closing down the Excel file:

```
$Excel.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
spps -n Excel
```

Comment: FYI: `ssps` is an alias for `Stop-Process`