# Kill a task based on its windows title

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to kill a process using it PID when a particular file is open on my computer, so that it doesn't interfere with another script

I have an excel sheet that is referenced by other parts of my system, it is fed information from many different sources I want to automate my workflow to work more smoothly.

```
Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "RASP transfer.xlsx - Excel"}  |Write-Output
```

I'm stuck on how to extract the PID and use it as a variable in a task  Stop-Process -ID PID

maybe I'm missing something help

in the end it should look something like this

```
Get-Process | 
Where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "RASP transfer.xlsx - Excel"}  |
Write-Output $pid=id | 
Stop-Process -ID $PID
```

edit: 6/6/19

Currently I'm able to identify the PID of the specific workbook 
by running
`Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "RASP transfer.xlsx - Excel"}  |Write-Output`

[image: powersell_output]

which I can identify here in the taskmanager 
[image: task manager output]

However when the files are run with scripts the excel file is hidden and can't be searched with the windows title....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the nice features of Powershell is that you can pass an object on the pipeline. You don't even need the Process ID:

```
Get-Process | Where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "RASP transfer.xlsx - Excel"} | Stop-Process
```

However it's important to know what type of object you're passing along at each stage in the pipeline. The input to Stop-Process in the line above is a `Process` object, that has an `ID` property.
If you wanted to get the Process ID you could assign it to a variable.

```
$PID = (Get-Process | Where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "RASP transfer.xlsx - Excel"}).ID
```

... which will *usually* only get a single Process ID because Excel doesn't allow opening the same spreadsheet in two windows. But you can't rely on the window title to be unique because it would be the same if you opened two copies of the same spreadsheet from different folders.

If you wanted to close all Excel windows, this code would get all the Excel windows' processes into an `Object[]` array:

```
$ExcelProcs = Get-Process | Where {$_.mainWindowTItle -like "* - Excel"}
```

`Stop-Process` is smart enough to use the array of `[Object]` as input and stop all their processes:

```
 $ExcelProcs | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the problem I'm running into is the excel document runs in the background/hidden with other scripts, I'm trying to close the file down by window title

ex 

`Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   1073      71    64744      72064      14.09  15080   1 EXCEL`

using its unique PID, which varies in this example its 15080

long story short I don't want to kill all the excel processes just the one associated with this PID
if you know of a better way please let me know

Comment: Sorry for the wordy answer - I meant to clarify how to use the pipeline in addition to solving your problem. The first line should have worked if the window title matched, but may have failed if the window is hidden. Can you see the hidden windows when you run this? `Get-Process | Where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "* Excel"} | Select * `

Comment: Negative, are you aware of a way to search for a hidden WindowTItle with powershell?

Comment: Can you give details about how the hidden Excel window was 'run with scripts'? Is the script running as a service account or other user? If there isn't a window, there will not be a window title.

Comment: `$scan = net file
$results = $scan | Select-String -SimpleMatch "C:\Users\nhutwelker\Dropbox"

foreach ($result in $results) {
    #Get id
    $id = $result.Line.Split(" ")[0]

    #Close file
    net file $id /close
    }

$file = 'C:\Users\nhutwelker\Dropbox\RASP transfer.xlsx'
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
$x1.Visible = $false
$wb.Save()
$wb.Close()
$x1.Quit()
Remove-Variable wb,x1`

Comment: This is the specific script causing the issue in theory the file should be closing on its own via the ComObject however sometimes it doesn't ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504265/close-excel-application-using-powershell) refers to `ReleaseCOMObject`, which may be the solution to the Excel doc not closing, the 'X' in your [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/).  I hope to hear how it works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just re- enable the visibility before you check for the open sheet with:

```
$x1.Visible = $true
$PID = (Get-Process | Where {$_.mainWindowTItle -eq "RASP transfer.xlsx - Excel"}).ID
```